# Converting a specific time format into another format

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert a certain time format. But unfriendly because of the current time format the index of certain characters (day, month) changes due to the number of characters before. I have been trying to use slicing to extract the right information. But because the indexes change I haven't had any luck. The desired time format is from datetime.

```
Current time format:
5/31/21, 6:30 AM
Desirade time format:
2021-06-12 20:41:06.447695
```

I was able to extract the hour and minute accurately but not with the day, month, year.

```
if 'PM' in start_time:
        string = ' PM'
    else:
        string = ' AM'

 minute = start_time[start_time.index(':') + 1:start_time.index(string)]
 hour = start_time[start_time.index(', ') + 2: start_time.index(':')]
```

Comment: You'll want to parse to datetime (strptime) with `"%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p"` and format to string with `datetime_obj.isoformat(' ')` - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: You should read the string containing the time using python's `datetime` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially want to convert this format `%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p` into this format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`.

So something like this:

```
d = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')
new_d = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

See [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for all the datetime `%` codes.